# Почему не записывается в бд имена файлов?

Tags: jquery, mysql

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.message_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var user_id = $(this).parent().find('.user_id').val();

    var wuser_id = $(this).parent().find('.wuser_id').val();

    var groups_id = $(this).parent().find('.groups_id').val();

    var messagesall = $(this).parent().find('.mess_txt').val(); 

    var messageimg = $(this).parent().find('.img_file');

    var messagevideo = $(this).parent().find('.video_file');

    var messageaudio = $(this).parent().find('.audio_file');

    if (messageimg.get(0).files.length != 0) {
      var messimg = messageimg[0].files[0].name.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    }else if (messagevideo.get(0).files.length != 0) {
      var messvideo = messagevideo[0].files[0].name.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    }else if (messageaudio.get(0).files.length != 0) {
      var messaudio = messageaudio[0].files[0].name.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    }else {
       messimg = "";
       messvideo = "";
       messaudio = "";
    }     
    console.log(messvideo);
    console.log(messimg);
    console.log(messaudio);



    var url = $(this).parent('.messaging').find('.message_form').attr('action');   

    var messages = $('.show_messages');


    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "wuser_id": wuser_id,
        "groups_id": groups_id,
        "chat_text": messagesall,
        "image": messimg,
        "video": messvideo,
        "audio": messaudio,       
        "send_mess": $(this).parent('.messaging').find(".send_btn").val()
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false, 
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',     
      success: function(response){  

          $('.mess_txt').val('');                  
              messages.append(response.user_answer);
              //messages.append(response.replier_answer);

        },
        error : function(){
          console.log('is error');
        }
      });
  });
```

```php
$data = $_POST;
    $w_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $g_id = (int) $_GET['group_id'];

    $id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;  

    $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".html", ".htm", ".pdf", ".js", ".sql", ".txt", ".py", ".cgi");
    $size = 1024000;     


    if (isset($data['send_mess'])) {
    $errors = array();
    $target = "../media/message_files/img/".basename($_FILES['myimage']['name']);
    $videotarget = "../media/message_files/video/".basename($_FILES['myvideo']['name']);
    $audiotarget = "../media/message_files/audio/".basename($_FILES['myaudio']['name']);
    $image = $_FILES['myimage']['name'];
    var_dump($image);
    $video = $_FILES['myvideo']['name'];
    $audio = $_FILES['myaudio']['name']; 
    $mess = trim(htmlspecialchars($data['chat_text']));    
    $result = preg_match("/[<>]/", $mess);    

  if ($result == TRUE) {
    $errors[] = 'Нехорошо так делать!';
  }
  foreach ($blacklist as $item)
  {
    if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['myimage']['name']))
    {
      $errors[] = "Запрещенный тип файла!";
    }
    if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['myvideo']['name']))
    {
      $errors[] = "Запрещенный тип файла!";
    } 
    if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['myaudio']['name']))
    {
      $errors[] = "Запрещенный тип файла!";
    }   
  }

    if (empty($errors)) {
    $user_id = intval($data['user_id']);        
    $wuser_id = intval($data['wuser_id']);
    $groups_id = intval($data['groups_id']);   
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $client = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $pubdate = date('d.m.Y H:i');


       $uploadfile = "images/".$_FILES['myimage']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'], $target);
       $uploadfile = "video/".$_FILES['myvideo']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myvideo']['tmp_name'], $videotarget);
       $uploadfile = "audio/".$_FILES['myaudio']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myaudio']['tmp_name'], $audiotarget);  


    $message = R::dispense('messaging');    
    $message->user_id = $user_id;
    $message->wuser_id = $wuser_id;
    $message->groups_id = $groups_id;    
    $message->message = $mess;
    $message->image = $image;
    $message->video = $video;
    $message->audio = $audio; 
    $message->ip = $ip;
    $message->client = $client;  
    $message->pubdate = $pubdate;
    $message->status = 0;

    R::store($message);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Без js php отрабатывает на отлично

Comment: Добавил в конец код файла обработчика

Comment: А где у вас происходит запись в БД?

Comment: $message->R::dispense('messaging'); ...etc - Здесь происходит запись и формирование бд

Comment: А лол, вы используете RedBeanPHP?

Comment: Аха, так точно!

Comment: Попробуйте в data передавать данные не в кавычках:
user_id: user_id, wuser_id:wuser_id и т.д.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло((

Comment: Ну в любом случае ковычек быть не должно. Поставьте в начале вашего php скрипта заглушку вида print(json_encode($_POST)); return; а в js выведет приходит или нет параметры success: function(response){console.log(response)}

Comment: Таким образом проверим доходят ли до сервера POST параметры

Comment: В консоле выходит пустой массив

Comment: Значит на сервер не приходят ваши параметры. А перед вызовом ajax в console.log() выведете все параметры которые вы передаете. Типа console.log(user_id,wuser_id) и проч.

Comment: Если вы проверили и все параметры в console.log до вызова аякса отображаются нормально, то оставьте в параметрах аякса только эти $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data:{ваши параметры},
                        url: url,
   success:function(response){console.log(response)}})

Comment: В консоле: Object { user_id: "1", wuser_id: "3", groups_id: "0", chat_text: "", image: "imgocean.jpg", send_mess: "" } -это я попробовал переслать audio. Но так запись в бд не произошла. А без заглушки - в бд параметры image, video, audio  NULL

Comment: А вот message - срабатывает отлично

Comment: Понятно, что с заглушкой ничего дальше return происходить не будет)
А вы уверены, что вам приходит не пустой массив $_FILES? По пробуйте в заглушке вернуть print_r(json_encode($_FILES)); return;

Comment: хм, а вот тут приходит пустой массив

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет файлы нужно обрабатывать не так. Оставлю вам пример кода в ответе, в комментариях не удобно.

Comment: Благодарю  вас, KordDEM!

Answer (score 0):

Что бы передать файл через ajax то требуется использовать FormData()

Ваш input

```
<input id="f_load" type="file" 
onchange="this.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML = this.value"/>
```

Js код:

```
$('#f_load').on('change', function(e) { // загрузка файла на сервер
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        /*Объявлем объект FormData*/
        var data = new FormData(); 
        $.each( this.files, function( key, value ){
            data.append( key, value );
        });// добавляем в объект данные по загруженным файлам
        // т.к. у нас есть данные помимо файлов то добавляем их аналогично

        data.append('user_id', user_id);
        data.append('wuser_id', wuser_id);

        data.append('groups_id', groups_id);
        data.append('chat_text', chat_text);

        data.append('send_mess', $(this).parent('.messaging').find(".send_btn").val());
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : 'POST',
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache:false,
            data : data, // теперь в массиве data у нас и данные о загруженном файле и доп данные
            success:function(response){
                    console.log(response)
            }
        })
```

Т.к. на стороне js гемморойно проверять, что за файл мы загружаем image, audio или video то эту часть придется дописать в php файле.